# Where can I find detailed documentation on Linux signals?

Tags: linux, signals, documentation

When we do `kill -l` we get a list of all the signals that are supported, but is there any man page that describes each signal in detail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) which, among other things, includes the following table:

```
   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                                 or death of controlling process
   SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
   SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
   SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
   SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
   SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
   SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
   SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
   SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
                                 readers
   SIGALRM      14       Term    Timer signal from alarm(2)
   SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
   SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
   SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
   SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated
   SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped
   SIGSTOP   17,19,23    Stop    Stop process
   SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop typed at terminal
   SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Terminal input for background process
   SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    Terminal output for background process
```

Comment: Hi , thanks  , although one line for each , but something is better than nothing :)

Comment: @IjazKhan that's a ~500 line man page. I only included the most relevant part, I suggest you read through it if you want more details.

Comment: @IjazKhan You can also try to find `error.h` in your system's libraries, there's some self-documenting code there